# jQuery form validation - how to iterate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a javascript - jQuery form validator.

I have an array with the regular expressions for each field, an array with the id of each field, and a third one with the error message I want to show the user if the entered value does not match the regular expression for each input.

I am trying to run a loop, and within it, create the .blur event listeners for every one of my form inputs.

My code is here:

```
$(function(){
    signUp()
    })

function signUp(){
var err = new Array();
var regex = new Array();
var mess = new Array();
var nm = new Array();
var i = 0;

// regex definitions //
regex[0] = /^[a-zA-Z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$/;regex[1] = regex[0]; //onoma , epwnimo
regex[2] = /^(\d){10}$/;regex[3] = /^([a-zA-Z\-]+\s)+\d{1,5}$/; //tilefwno , dieuthinsi
regex[4] = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;regex[5] = regex[4]; // email
regex[6] = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\_]?[\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/;regex[7] = regex[6]; // password

// message definitions //
mess[0] = 'Το όνομα πρέπει να αποτελείται μόνο απο λατινικούς χαρακτήρες και κενά!';
mess[1] = 'Το επώνυμο πρέπει να αποτελείται μόνο απο λατινικούς χαρακτήρες και κενά!';
mess[2] = 'Το τηλέφωνο πρέπει να αποτελείται από 10 ψηφία!';
mess[3] = 'H διεύθυνση πρέπει να περιέχει οδό και αριθμό με λατινικούς χαρακτήρες, π.χ. Ellinos Stratiwtou 13!';
mess[4] = 'Εισάγετε μια έγκυρη διεύθυνση email!';mess[5] = mess[4];
mess[6] = 'Το password πρέπει να αποτελείται απο λατινικούς χαρακτήρες, αριθμούς, _ και -';mess[7] = mess[6];

// div name definitions //
nm[0] = '#onoma';nm[1] = '#epwn';nm[2] = '#tele';nm[3] = '#addr';
nm[4] = '#ema';nm[5] = '#emai';nm[6] = '#pasw';nm[7] = '#conpass';

for(;i<8;i++){
    $(nm[i]).blur(function(){
        alert(nm[i])
        })
    }
}
```

I was hoping the code above would alert me the name of the form input that triggered the blur event, but all I get is undefined, and when I try to `alert(i)`, within the `.blur` function, it always shows 8, no matter what field I run this on.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I have not posted my html since it's just a form, but I will post it if needed.

Comment: You should use the live (http://api.jquery.com/live/) with your blur event and use some class to bind it to all the specific elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the `for` loop? And why set the `blur()` event inside of the loop like that?. I don't understand your reasoning behind this. Instead of creating an array of ids, you can just give your fields a class an assign the event on that class.

```
$('.field').blur(function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Edit:
The idea is to use objects instead of arrays and basically create one object with all the regex and errors and one function to evaluate the fields. Something like this:

```
var filters = {
    name : {
        re : /^[a-zA-Z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$/,
        error : 'Name Error!'
    },
    email : {
        re : /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/,
        error : 'E-Mail Error!'
    },
    password : {
        re : /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\_]?[\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/,
        error : 'Password Error!'
    }
};

var validate = function(klass, str) {
    var valid = true,
        error = '';
    for (var f in filters) {
        var re = new RegExp(f);
        if (re.test(klass)) {
            if (str && !filters[f].re.test(str)) {
                error = filters[f].error;
                valid = false;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return {
        error: error,
        valid: valid
    }
};

$('.field').blur(function() {
    var test = validate(
        $(this).attr('class'),
        $(this).val()
    );
    if (!test.valid) {
        $('#errors').append('<p>' + test.error + '</p>');
    }
});
```

Comment: That way I would have to give the fields a total of 6 classes based on the function I like to run on blur for each type of field(email, address, password etc.), so that I can validate them all?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Sadly I am not skilled enough to completely understand your code. I will have to do some homework and return to award rep.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<8;i++) {
    $(nm[i]).blur(function(e) {
        alert(e.target.id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why write your own, when [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and other jQuery based validation plug-ins exist? The default messages are available in multiple languages. You'd just have to define your custom messages when needed.