# jQuery Validation Form - Ensure no numbers in First and Last name input only letters

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jQuery to validate a form (firstName, lastName, and email). I have successfully validate the email portion of the form however I would like to know how to validate the firstName and lastName input fields?

jQuery Validation script:

email validation (working):

```
var patt =  /^.+@.+[.].{2,}$/i;

    if(!patt.test(ele.val())) {
        jVal.errors = true;
                    emailInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('X').show();
        ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
            }else{
                    emailInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
                    ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
            }

        },
```

firstName validation (not working):

```
var patt =  /^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/;

        if(!patt.test(ele.val()).length < 2) {
            jVal.errors = true;
                firstNameInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('X').show();
                ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
                firstNameInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show()
                ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
            }
        },
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  The [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) has this functionality already built in.

Comment: I [reinvented the wheel](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/) but on acid!

Comment: **@user1584751** here's [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674148/jquery-form-validation-how-to-iterate/9674338#9674338) I posted a while ago for a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone the validation jQuery script is validating my form properly. :)

Answer (score 2):

call https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js at last of html code

```
$('#formId').validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 30,
                    pattern: "^[a-zA-Z_]*$",
                    required: true
                },
                 lastname: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 30, 
                    pattern: "^[a-zA-Z_]*$",
                    required:true
                }
     },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

we must have found the same jquery form validation page...
any who im writing a form as well with it and  found answer to your question - hope ya still need it if not help others maybe...

```
   var regex = new RegExp("[0-9]");
   var match = regex.exec($('#firstname').val());
   if(ele.val().length < 2 || match) {
//do stuff
```

so the first part in the if is not related but the Match part is, checks if there are any numbers in the string and  if so ... in my case i have it showing the error div...I didn't want to copy all of the code.

Hope this helps
Joe
CustomWebsites4Less.com

If ya need an example i should have this on a live site within a the week...