# jquery custom validation script without plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i used to use jquery validation plugin but because of lack of this plugin with wysiwyg plugins i wrote a simple script to validate my form

i tried to do it like this

```
function validateArticle(formData, jqForm, options) { 
  $('#errors').empty();
  if ($('#editor').val() == 0) { 
    $('#errors').show();
    $('#errors').append('<li>please enter your article body</li>');
    return false; 
  } 
  if ($('#ArticleTitle').val() == 0) { 
    $('#errors').show();
    $('#errors').append('<li>please enter your article title</li>');
    return false; 
  }
  $('#errors').hide();
  return true ;
}
```

i found to 1 problem when it validate the form it's validating it field by field so the errors messages doesn't appear at once

i tried to do something like

```
var errors = [];
function validateArticle(formData, jqForm, options) { 
  $('#errors').empty();
  if ($('#editor').val() == 0) { 
    errors.push('<li>please enter your article body</li>');
    var invalid = 1 ;
    return false; 
  } 
  if ($('#ArticleTitle').val() == 0) { 
    errors.push('<li>please enter your article title</li>');
    var invalid = 1 ;
    return false; 
  }
  if(invalid == 1){
    $.each(errors , function(i, val) { 
      $('#errors').append(errors [i]); 
    });
  }

  $('#errors').hide();
  return true ;
}
```

i tried to push errors as array elements and loop through them in case of invalid is true
bu this one doesn't work at it all ?

is there any way to make it work ?

Comment: If you're trying to make your own solution check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674148/jquery-form-validation-how-to-iterate/9674338#9674338, it may help.

Comment: @elclanrs very nice function but would i append errors in UL using it? also how will i validate null values not only regx ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('#editor').val() == 0)   // This is checking if value is 0
```

This does not make sense..
Try

```
if ($('#editor').val() == '') //Instead check for empty string
```

**EDIT**
Also you seem to be hiding the error's div in the end.

```
 $('#errors').hide();
```

Try this code Instead

```
$('#validate').on('click', function() {
    var errors = [];
    var html = '<ul>' ;
    valid = true;
    $('#errors').empty();
    if ($('#editor').val() == '') {
        errors.push('<li>please enter your article body</li>');
        valid = false;
    }
    if ($('#ArticleTitle').val() == '') {
        errors.push('<li>please enter your article title</li>');
         valid = false;
    }
    if (!valid) {
        html += errors.join('') + '</ul>' 
            $('#errors').append(html);

    }
    else{
        $('#errors').hide();
    }
    return valid;
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/WF2J9/1/)

Comment: Or omit the comparison altogether and let JS do its thing...`if (!$('#editor').val()) { ... }`

Comment: thank you so much i added them to function so i can call it inside the .AjaxForm options it still show 1 error only not all of errors

Comment: just nothing thank you so much it works :) i thought you return true in case of validation not return the variable it self :)