# How to narrow down the reason for failing regular expression validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

Is there a way to find out what kind of error (text is to short, long, invalid characters) triggered a match failure in a regular expression such as the ones below?

```
regexes = {
    name: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,32}$/,
    title: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,128}$/,
    text: /^[\w' -]+$/,
    email: /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/,
    phone: /^[0-9-\/]{3,32}$/
};
```

Comment: Check my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674148/jquery-form-validation-how-to-iterate/9674338#9674338).

Comment: I can see that you can check the type of error (name or email) but I don't see a way to check if the input is too short or too long?

Comment: You can use the `length` property for that or this regex: `/.{3,}/` which means at least 3 characters.

Comment: Not an answer, but... your email regex will exclude my (valid) email address.  For all practical purposes, *absolutely **anything** is allowed* to the left of the `@` sign, including another `@` sign if it's escaped properly.

Comment: I give it a lot of thinking about email. Web site is targeting local area (the Balkans) and there are just a few variations among email services (gmail, yahoo mail, msn, facebook, and couple which are ending with .rs) and none of them have more then six letters. I am a bit curios, how does your email ends?

Comment: gmail specifically allows the use of `+` to amend your email address, so if my email is `stephen@gmail.com` then I will also receive mail sent to `stephen+stackoverflow@gmail.com`  You are not allowing `+` -- only (lowercase) letters, numbers, underscore, dot, and dash. I also have my own domain, so I can have `anyname^that!I~want`@`mydomain.net` -- it is the **left** of the `@` that you are far too strict on.

Comment: You'd have to break your regex's into specific per-test sun-regexps e.g. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,32}$/` becomes `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*/` (invalid characters), `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,}$/` (too short) and `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{,32}$/` (too long), then you can find out which one(s) failed and inform the user appropriately.

Comment: Do not validate address in such a simple way: you will reject many valid emails. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part. "this is a valid email"@example.com address(comment)@example.com andré.müller@example.com are *all* valid addresses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a regex is matching a string or not, but it does not give you a reason why it failed.

If you want to know that, you need to split your regex and test all conditions in different runs. e.g. for your name patter `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,32}$/`

1. Min length: `/^.{3,}/` if this is failing it is too short.
2. Max length: `/.{0,32}/` if this is failing it is too long.
3. Valid characters: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*$/` if this is failing the string contains not allowed characters.